# Error in collapsible panel in Sencha application

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I am new in Sencha. I try to add a dynamic collapsible panel in application page where I need to show data in title and information in collapsible panel, but it's not showing any data not even showing any error. I am fully confused what I am doing wrong, please help me.

```
        Ext.define('myapp.view.applications.DetailSummarySection',{
            extend:'Ext.Container',
            xtype:'applications_detailsummarysection',

            config:{
                emptyText:'No data found',
                appId:null,
                items:[
                    {
                        itemId:'details_summary',
                        tpl:Ext.create('Ext.XTemplate',
                            '<tpl for="details">',
                                   //....................
                            '</tpl>'
                        )
                    },
                    {
                        xtype: 'formpanel',
                        collapsible: true,
                        collapsed: true,
                        layout: 'hbox',
                        bodyPadding: 10,
                        title: 'Dates',
                        items: [{
                            xtype: 'textfield',
                            name: 'name',
                            label: 'Name'
                        }]
                   },
                    {
                        xtype:'toolbar',
                        itemId:'popup_bar',
                        docked:'bottom',
                        border:'0px',
                        height:'54px',
                        style:{'background-color':'#1E94C0'},

                        defaults:{
                            flex:1,
                            height:'48px',
                            padding:'0 0 0 0',
                            style:{ 'line-height':'10px','margin':'3px 0 0 0 ','border-radius':'0px', 'color':'#ffffff', 'background-color':'transparent', 'border':'0px'}
                        },
                        items:[
                            {
                                text:'Comments',
                                itemId:'notes',
                                cls:'pop-btn',
                                iconCls:'action',
                                iconAlign:'top'
                            },
                            {
                                text:'Feedback',
                                itemId:'feedBackBtn',
                                cls:'pop-btn',
                                iconCls:'star',
                                iconAlign:'top'
                            },
                            {
                                text:'CVS',
                                itemId:'cv',
                                cls:'pop-btn',
                                iconCls:'compose',
                                iconAlign:'top'
                            },
                            {
                                text:'Reject',
                                cls:'pop-btn',
                                itemId:'rejectBtn',
                                iconAlign:'top',
                                iconCls:'trash'
                            },
                            {
                                text:'Reject',
                                cls:'pop-btn',
                                itemId:'rejectCvSpecBtn',
                                hidden:true,
                                iconAlign:'top',
                                iconCls:'trash'

                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no `config` property for container. You will have to set the `items` array to the container and not to the `config` attribute.

Code as shown below.

```
Ext.define('myapp.view.applications.DetailSummarySection', {
    extend: 'Ext.Container',
    xtype: 'applications_detailsummarysection',
    emptyText: 'No data found',
    appId: null,
    items: [{
        itemId: 'details_summary',
        tpl: Ext.create('Ext.XTemplate',
            '<tpl for="details">',
            //....................
            '</tpl>'
        )
    }, {
        xtype: 'formpanel',
        collapsible: true,
        collapsed: true,
        layout: 'hbox',
        bodyPadding: 10,
        title: 'Dates',
        items: [{
            xtype: 'textfield',
            name: 'name',
            label: 'Name'
        }]
    }, {
        xtype: 'toolbar',
        itemId: 'popup_bar',
        docked: 'bottom',
        border: '0px',
        height: '54px',
        style: {
            'background-color': '#1E94C0'
        },

        defaults: {
            flex: 1,
            height: '48px',
            padding: '0 0 0 0',
            style: {
                'line-height': '10px',
                'margin': '3px 0 0 0 ',
                'border-radius': '0px',
                'color': '#ffffff',
                'background-color': 'transparent',
                'border': '0px'
            }
        },
        items: [{
            text: 'Comments',
            itemId: 'notes',
            cls: 'pop-btn',
            iconCls: 'action',
            iconAlign: 'top'
        }, {
            text: 'Feedback',
            itemId: 'feedBackBtn',
            cls: 'pop-btn',
            iconCls: 'star',
            iconAlign: 'top'
        }, {
            text: 'CVS',
            itemId: 'cv',
            cls: 'pop-btn',
            iconCls: 'compose',
            iconAlign: 'top'
        }, {
            text: 'Reject',
            cls: 'pop-btn',
            itemId: 'rejectBtn',
            iconAlign: 'top',
            iconCls: 'trash'
        }, {
            text: 'Reject',
            cls: 'pop-btn',
            itemId: 'rejectCvSpecBtn',
            hidden: true,
            iconAlign: 'top',
            iconCls: 'trash'

        }]
    }]
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply When I remove **config** then I get an error    `summarySectionView.getItems().getByKey('popup_bar').getItems().getByKey('notes').candidate_id = record.data.candidate_id;`   Console show me error after `summarySectionView.getItems().getByKey('popup_bar')....`

Comment: Are you able to view the panel now?

Comment: oh! okay. But I am able to view the panel in a sencha fiddle with the same code.

Comment: Thanks Gilsha now its working ,I have made some mistake in my side.